# How do you fade between two values using geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a lot of points on a plane that go from a random rotation to pointing towards a mesh in my animation. The problem is that I want the points to be shown turning instead of an instantaneous switch using the switch node.

I'm using version 3.2.2 and there is no mix node of any sort that I can think of. The math node is so far not helpful.

Comment: Please avoid polluting your questions extraneous text like "please help"

Comment: okay i will do that.

Comment: Well, Markus has already given you an answer, but just a tip in general: when you say "there is no mix node of any sort", it might help if you just use the _Search_ function in the _Geometry Nodes Editor_. If you want a mix node of any sort, just enter "mix" in the search field and this would have shown you _MixRGB_ as result. The search function can really help you out sometimes, especially if you do not use it from the _Add_ menu (`Shift`+`A`) but directly open the search with `F3` which gives even more results.

Comment: I mean i did look up mix and i saw mixrgb but the rgb made me think it would not be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have the *Mix* node, but you have the **MixRGB** node, which displays as "Mix":

[image]

This node has been used for vector [lerping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) for a long time (I used it this way for the first time in B2.79), taking advantage of the fact vectors and color are stored in the same way (sometimes color also has alpha component, but for most versions it didn't seem to be the case).

[image]

Reproducing the *Mix* node (at least in its default mode with the same name 'Mix') is very simple:

$$a(1-t) + bt$$

It's a weighted average, where $t = 0.5$ divides both $a$ and $b$ by two and adds them together (normal average), and for all $t$, the sum of $t$ and $1-t$ is exactly $1$.

[image]